# Space is sometimes gobbled with microtype and url

Tags: pdftex, urls, microtype

I experimented with condensing URLs slightly and thought everything worked fine, until I noted a problem in the final proofreading. The *first* "this" in the following minimal example seems to have no space following it (there's "thislacks" in the output, with different fonts though).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{microtype}
\def\test#1{\textls[-10]{\url{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Note that \test{this} lacks following space, but \test{this} and \test{this} is fine.
\end{document}
```

I already found out that changing the definition to

```
\def\test#1{\textls[-10]{\url{#1}}\relax}
```

repairs the problem, but I really wonder how this could happen in the first place. For without explanation of what went wrong I can never be sure if the remedy really works for all cases, can I?

---

**EDIT:** Here's what `\listfiles` created:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
microtype.sty    2009/03/27 v2.3d Micro-typography with pdfTeX (RS)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
microtype.cfg    2009/03/27 v2.3d microtype main configuration file (RS)
  mt-cmr.cfg    2008/02/29 v1.9a microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman 
(RS)
 ***********
```

Comment: The MWE you provide works fine with me. Could you please issue `\listfile` before `\documentclass` -- it will put a list of file versions into the `.log`, and then copy it here, so that we can see whether the problem is version-dependent?

Comment: @tohecz "! Undefined control sequence." is probably not what you wanted to hear :)

Comment: Ah ok, I have an older version of `microtype` here (`2007/01/21 v2.0`). I'll test at home on TL2012.

Comment: You are using a very old version. It works fine for me with the current one (2.5a, 2013/05/23), so you should just update `microtype`.

Comment: @Robert Hm, any idea how far behind the default update strategy for Ubuntu is on this issue?